# C# Creating Authentic Camera /w head

Tags: c#, matrix, xna, physics

I've been dabbling with this problem for a few days now, which is really embarrassing, cause you'd think it would be really easy to fix.

I'm working on making the Camera function for a game I'm making in XNA (yes, I know XNA is no longer supported, please stop telling me). It is being developed for the Oculus Rift, and I got it partially working, with joints from Shoulders to Neck, and Neck to Head.
The eyes are what is currently troubling me. Currently, when looking straight forward, it works fine. But as soon as I rotate (Pitch), the eyes do not follow. They basically get stuck on the same offset (like, x+2 and x-2 from camera position), which means that when I turn 180 degrees around, the eyes are now swapped. So my left vision is my right camera, and vice versa.

Here's my code:
[CameraController.cs]

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Vector3 leftEyePosition = GetEyePosition(Eyes.Left);
        Vector3 rightEyePosition = GetEyePosition(Eyes.Right);

        _leftEyeCamera.Update(gameTime, leftEyePosition, NeckHead.Yaw, NeckHead.Pitch, NeckHead.Roll, 2);
        _rightEyeCamera.Update(gameTime, rightEyePosition, NeckHead.Yaw, NeckHead.Pitch, NeckHead.Roll, -2);
    }

    private Vector3 GetEyePosition(Eyes eyes)
    {
        Matrix neckHead = GetHeadPositions();

        Vector3 eye = (eyes == Eyes.Left ? neckHead.Left : neckHead.Right);
        Vector3 eyePosition = NeckHead.Position;
        return (eye + eyePosition);
    }

    private Matrix GetHeadPositions()
    {
        Matrix shoulderNeck = ShoulderNeck.GetMatrix();
        Matrix neckHead = NeckHead.GetMatrix()*shoulderNeck;

        return neckHead;
    }
```

[Joint.cs]

```
public class Joint
{
    private float _pitch;
    private Vector3 _position;
    private float _roll;
    private float _yaw;

    public Joint(Joint childJoint, Vector3 position)
    {
        ChildJoint = childJoint;
        Position = position;
    }

    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }

    public float Yaw { get; set; }

    public float Pitch { get; set; }

    public float Roll { get; set; }

    public Joint ChildJoint { get; private set; }

    public Matrix GetMatrix()
    {
        return Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Yaw, Pitch, Roll);
    }
}
```

[FpsCamera.cs Update method]

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Vector3 position, float yaw, float pitch, float roll)
{
    Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(pitch, yaw, roll);
    Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Forward, rotationMatrix);

    Vector3 target = transformedReference + position;

    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, target, rotationMatrix.Up);
}
```

As far as I can tell, this should be working, right? I think it might be a problem with one of the matrices, but if I knew, I wouldn't be asking, so... Anyone got a hunch?

Complete classes:
http://pastebin.com/zUVwAPFt
http://pastebin.com/jTbnNsJm

Thanks
Bjarke

Ps. Shorted it down for all you guys asking.

Comment: Nobody will read all of this code.

Comment: @pinckerman 'all of this code'. You do realize how little it is, right? Besides you don't even need to read more than the Update method and the Get methods. Unless of course you want to get a general overview of how everything works, which I don't think should be needed anyway.

Comment: That's why you should write only the needed code, it's easier to understand.

Comment: You're saying it's easier to understand code, out of context? o_O Excuse me when I ask, where did you learn to program?

Comment: Very funny. I'm just saying that if you write a small bunch of code instead of the whole class you will receive more feedbacks or answers, that was only a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah alright, I get it. I didn't mean to be rude, I just simply don't see how this question can be answered, by only looking at the Update and Get methods, seeing as I'm pretty sure I have already tried everything to get that working. I don't think that is where the problem is, after all.

Comment: One question - why are you adding the matrices `shoulderNeck` and `neckHead` ? Shouldn't you be multiplying them in order to do obtain the correct position for that part of the skeleton?

Comment: And @pinckerman is right - it isn't the point that people need to understand code in context. This is a collaborative site and thus, people expect you to have put in some effort and narrowed down the problem or have a reproducible, short example. It isn't feasible for someone to dig through reams of code "for context". Your question is more likely to remain unanswered in such situations.

Comment: Alright, I went ahead and shorted down all the unnecessary code. The complete FpsCamera and CameraController classes are uploaded on pastebin.

Comment: After some hours of debugging I've come the conclusion that the 'GetMatrix' from Joints is always only returning a fixed value, no matter rotation or position. Am I doing something wrong in relation to matrices? My understanding of how matrices works isn't the best in the world, to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. Silly me. After about a week of researching, I finally went to see if what I thought I was completely sure of, wasn't true. I'd mixed up what directions Yaw and Pitch works, which obviously resulted in VERY odd-working code.

So in the end, if anyone has a problem similar to this, if it is not the Yaw, Pitch or Roll axis that's a problem, you wont find the answer here.